# Error while starting resource manager daemon in Hadoop 2.6

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

This is the error I get while starting resource manager daemon in `Hadoop 2.6`:

```
[hadoop@master hadoop]$ sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 60: [: master.out: integer expression expected
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-master.phd.com
Error: Could not find or load main class master.log
```

Comment: could you post your config files?

Comment: If the script tells you that there is an error on line 60, you should look at line 60 or at least post its content here. Aparently you provided some none integer where the script expects and integer.